# Shutil and os help to copy files

Tags: python, shutil, file-copying

```
import shutil
import os
import time

os.chdir('c:\\User\\user\\')

time.sleep(10)
shutil.copytree('Pictures', 'E:\\')
```

So I have wasted all day just so I can steal files from my friend but no matter what I do nothing f*** works!!! Sorry for being angry but for crying out loud... I am a beginner so I haven't experienced the hell programmers go trough. Ty for helping!

Comment: By the way the time.sleep is just for testing

Comment: Oh and I almost forgot the error comes from the path and every person that I "try" to learn from they use a different looking path. What?!?!?!?!?

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. "nothing works" is not descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your problem solved, it is a good idea to *report the error message that you get*, which was *PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'E:\\'.*

The docs for `shutil.copytree()` say

> Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at `src` to a directory
> named `dst` and return the destination directory. `dirs_exist_ok` dictates whether to
> raise an exception in case `dst` or any missing parent directory already exists

This makes it clear that you have to *name* a fresh target folder and that this should normally not exist.

Using `os.chdir()` overcomplicates things. All you have to do is specify the full path of the source folder and the full path of the new target folder in your call to `copytree()`, so that you end up with a 2-line program, like this:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(r"C:\Users\user\Pictures",r"E:\mynewdir")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for being one of the people ho help others